# @ManyToOne unidirectional mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an Entity class **Payment** which has Entity class **PaymentMethod** with **Many to one** relationship.

Now since My PaymentMethod is master table.

So I want to save payment without affecting the master table PaymentMethod.

But every time I save the Payment it inserts a new row in PaymentMethod too. I am unable to figure out why.

I am using SpringData save.

**Payment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="payment")
public class Payment implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
  
   @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
   @JoinColumn(name="payment_method_id")
   private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

  //getter and setters
}
```

**PaymentMethod.java**

```
@Table(name="paymentmethod")
 public class PaymentMethod implements Serializable {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 
 @Column(name="name",unique=true ,nullable=false)
 private String name;

 //GETTER AND SETTERS
}
```

**PAYMENT_METHOD DATA**

```
ID | NAME 
1  | AA
2  | BB
3  | CC
```

After payment get save
PAYMENT_METHOD entry with duplicate name ?

I am unable to figure out why.

For saving I have created a simple CRUDRepository for Payment type

calling save entity of repository.

Please suggest where I am falling out.

whenever code executes this line :

```
paymentMethodRepository.findByName(payment.getPaymentMethod().getName());
```

It gives error as

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.enrollment.domain.Payment.paymentMethod -> com.enrollment.domain.PaymentMethod
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.noCascade(CascadingAction.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:870)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:870)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:870)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:870)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:870)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$8.cascade(CascadingAction.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1241)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:285)
```

I am unable to figure out how the code works if trying to flush it when I call finder method from repository.

Am I missing something?

Issue solved thanks @JB and @spiritwalker, But unable to find the exact root cause, so just discussing the behavior may be the discussion will add on to knowledge.

```
Behaviour ..

Open Transaction
   1. validate
   2. save child
   3. validate and update 
   4. save parent
Close Transaction

it was giving above error.

Now, after code change it worked

Open Transaction
   1. validate
   2. validate and update 
   3. save child
   4. save parent
Close Transaction
```

Comment: The problem is that at step 3, you're executing a database query. So, before executing it, Hibernate flushes its in-memory changes  to make sure that the query can see the new values stored in memory, but not stored in database yet. And since the in-memory state is not valid, you get this exception.

Comment: Correct, But since i am still in transaction(readonly=false) , so don't you think , on executing select query ,flush  should not happen. [ note: select was executed for master data] .

Comment: No, I don't think so. Suppose in a transaction, you're creating many payments, and then later in the same transaction, you want to list all the payments of a given type. You definitely want the payments you just created to be included in the result (just like if you inserted the payments using JDBC). That's why the session is flushed.

Comment: But if i want to read uncommitted data, then i will make isolation level read uncommited.

Comment: Isolation is used to isolate between **different** transactions. You're inserting things and reading them in a unique transaction. A transaction sees what it has inserted.

Answer (score 5):

Start by removing the cascades, since you precisely don't want to create/modify the PaymentMethod when you create/modify a Payment.

Then, when you create a Payment, assign it the existing PaymentMethod you want it to be associated with:

```
PaymentMethod existingPaymentMethod = em.find(PaymentMethod.class, idOfThePaymentMethod);
Payment payment = new Payment();
payment.setPaymentMethod(existingPaymentMethod);
em.persist(payment);
```

Comment: spring repository gives save method which internally does the same if id is null

Comment: If id of what is null? The spring repository takes the objects you give him. If you give him a new PaymentMethod instead of giving him an existing one, it won't work as you want to.

Comment: You correct but after setting correct object still working same way. Unable to figure out why?

Comment: Maybe if you showed your code we could tell you. Edit your question.

Comment: It may me transaction issue because i am calling get method , in the log it trying to do flush

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24658/discussion-between-zuned-ahmed-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: I won't chat about code that you don't want to show. It would be sterile.

Comment: OK, I've read your code, and I can't find where the problem is, sorry. I suggest using a debugger and stepping through each line to check that the code does what you want it to do.

Comment: issue solve please read the updated comment once more and put some knowledge if possible. Thanks for your spontaneous reply.

Answer (score 3):

remove **cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}** from your Payment entity.

Since PaymentMethod is a master table like you said, you do not want to have any cascading operation happens from Payment down to PaymentMethod.

Comment: you need retrieve a PaymentMethod entity instance and assign it to Payment entity.

Comment: if that is the case, can you make sure that retrieving PaymentMethod and saving Payment are happening in the same transaction? If not? maybe you can try merging PaymentMethod entity instance back into persistent context and then assign it to Payment entity. But like @JB said, attaching your code will be helpful.

Comment: issue solve please read the updated comment once more and put some knowledge if possible. Thanks for your spontaneous reply.